# Problems with Dynamic Div Width

Tags: css, dynamic, html

From everything I've read, my CSS *should* have the left hand text resize to fit the remaining space, but it doesn't seem to work in Chrome (ironically IE9 renders something right for once).
Bit of a noob with CSS so there's undoubtedly something I'm missing (and stuff that I don't need).

The website can be seen here;
baradineholdings.com.au

HTML;

```
<div id="internal">
    <div id="image">
        <img src="" alt="" width="563" height="422"/>
    </div> <!-- end #image -->
    <div id="content">
        <p> A whole heap of content goes here. </p>
    </div> <!-- end #content -->
</div> <!-- end #internal -->
```

CSS;

```
#internal {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#image {
    width: 563px;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}

#content {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    float: left;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with the

```
float: left;
```

in #content. If you remove this you get the desired effect in all browsers. You'll also need to set the display on #content to be:

```
display: inline;
```

Otherwise your backround-color will cause issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I turns out I needed both those suggestions, just removing float:left; didn't work by itself, I still had the same issue with chrome. Adding display: inline; fixed it up though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#content {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    float: left;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Try to add

```
clear: both;
```